# Очистить все таблицы mysql подходящие под одно условие

Tags: mysql, sql

В базе данных mysql имеется несколько таблиц вида:
temp_ids_1
temp_ids_5
temp_ids_8
temp_ids_12
и т. д.

Т.е. различаются они лишь ID в конце имени таблицы.
Можно ли написать такой запрос, чтобы одним махом очистить все эти таблицы. Т.е. что-то вроде

```
TRUNCATE `temp_ids_*`
```

Comment: Нельзя. Вам надо читать список таблиц из information_schema и динамически генерировать запросы. И при первой возможности надо пересмотреть структуру БД таким образом, что бы подобные задачи в принципе не появлялись

Answer (score 1):

Если все таблицы имеют одинаковую структуру, создайте единую надтаблицу на MERGE Storage. Truncate такой таблицы вызовет очистку всех входящих в объединение таблиц.

Правда, у меня наблюдается странный косяк на Server version: 5.7.16-log MySQL Community Server (GPL). После TRUNCATE надтаблицы SELECT из неё показывает отсутствие записей, а SELECT из отдельных таблиц - что записи на месте. И только после вставки в отдельные таблицы хотя бы одной записи обнаруживается, что записей, что отображались, на самом деле нет...

UPD: Т.е. после TRUNCATE `table` необходимо выполнить FLUSH TABLE `table`.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1) sql запрос:

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'TRUNCATE TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
    AS statement
FROM 
    information_schema.tables 
WHERE 
    table_name LIKE 'temp_ids_%';
```

Очистети тебе все таблицы, что начинаются на "temp_ids_%". Там можно любое условие сделать;-)

2) bash скрипт:

```
mysql -Nse 'show tables' -pDB_PASSWORD -u DB_USER DB_NAME | while read table;
do mysql -e "TRUNCATE TABLE $table" -pDB_PASSWORD -u DB_USER DB_NAME; done
```

Comment: sql запрос не работает. statement получается TRUNCATE TABLE temp_ids_1,temp_ids_2,temp_ids_3,temp_ids_9;
(запрос выполнял в phpmyadm, поэтому вижу его), но таблицы не очищаются

Comment: Есть вариант, что ты пытаешься очистить таблицв, а там есть к ним связи. Так что прийдется оключить их контроль:
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

Еще есть один способ, если ты видишь, что запрос строится нормальный. Запиши его в файл, а в bash выпони sql из файла:
mysql -u myuser -p mydatabase < file_with_sql_truncate.sql

Comment: Еще вариант, удалить таблицы;) А вторым запросом создать их(CREATE TABLE).

SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
    AS statement
FROM 
    information_schema.tables 
WHERE 
    table_schema = 'database' AND 
    table_name LIKE 'temp_ids_%'
;

Еще добавил фильтр по базе, так как имена таблиц могут повторятся, а базы будут разные.